# How to create token from stripe card form

Tags: flutter, stripe-payments, flutter-packages, flutter-stripe

How can we generate a token from stripe card form in flutter using `flutter_stripe`: `^9.0.0+1`

Link - https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_stripe

```js
final TokenData tokenData = await Stripe.instance.createToken(
    const CreateTokenParams.card(
        params: CardTokenParams(
            type: TokenType.Card
        ),
    ),
);
```

Here we are not giving cardNumber, cvc and expiryDate so how Stripe can the generate token?

Comment: You should follow flutter-stripe README https://github.com/flutter-stripe/flutter_stripe#card-payments. There are 3 patterns and each of them has different approach of collection card number, cvc and expiry date

Comment: in the documentation there is no example usage of how to create token using CardFormField().

can anyone tell us how to create token only using card details please.

Comment: Did you find the answer? I'm stuck to the same problem.

Comment: @Sunil Unfortunately, no.